# Context action mode not showing icons on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop

The `context` mode does not show the default icons(copy,paste) on `lollipop` , it works or other versions. Following is the theme unser `values-21`

```
<resources>

    <style name="BaseTheme.MainTheme">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/grey</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BaseTheme.MainTheme.WithNavDrawer">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/grey</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

[image]

Comment: Your theme is probably making the system tint the icons the same color as the action mode overlay. Press the supposed action areas to know whether they are actually there. If they are, then you would need to modify your theme to either change the overlay color or change the tint on the icons

Comment: I tried clicking on the bar , the icons are not there.